# Object dissappearing when rotating

Tags: nurbs-surface

I m new to Blender and I am using Blender 2.8
My problem is that after an operation where I loft a Nurbs circle along a NURBS path using bevel and applied a subsequent taper using a second NURBS cirle to I get an object which is essentially correct but when I orbit in the view the object gradually disappears and the reappears. (I am building a surface that has to curve along two axes) In 3DS Max this is usually resolved by flipping normals but I do not know the setting for this in Blender 2.83

Could someone advise me how to fix this?

Comment: Your question description is, as it is, too brief for anyone to formulate a proper answer. Text probably won't do your question justice, so please consider adding some screenshots or possibly even putting the .blend file up for download if you want people to be able to really help you. However, from what I can understand, you're probably just clipping through the object. Try zooming out or adjusting the `Clip Start` value for the viewport.

Comment: Sounds interesting, send us the blendfile using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com